# Parallel using ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

In my app, I am getting periodic GPS coordinates which I add to an ArrayList, while there is an AsyncTask running, sending the coordinates to a server.

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
....extra code here

        locationUpdates.add(locationData);

....extra code here
    }
```

and in AsyncTask:

```
    private class InsertTripDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                for (int i = locationUpdates.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    ArrayList<PropertyInfo> props = new ArrayList<PropertyInfo>();
                    props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("TripID", tripID, String.class));
                    props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("LocationTime", locationUpdates.get(i).LocationTime, String.class));
                    props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("Latitude", locationUpdates.get(i).Latitude, String.class));
                    props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("Longitude", locationUpdates.get(i).Longitude, String.class));
                    props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("TripSpeed", locationUpdates.get(i).SpeedKMPH, String.class));

                    String response = MyUtils.getResponse("InsertTripDetail", props);

                    if (response.equals("yes")) {
                        locationUpdates.remove(i);
                        sentData++;
                        SetSentBufferedData();
                        PlayTone();
                    }
                    PlayInternetAlertIfNeeded();
                }

                if(isCancelled() && (locationUpdates.size()==0))
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }
    }
```

I believe this could cause a problem as both threads will simultaneously manipulate the ArrayList. Any suggestion on how to do that "safely"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe this could cause a problem as both threads will simultaneously manipulate the ArrayList. Any suggestion on how to do that "safely"

Whenever a non-atomic object is shared between two threads, and at least one of those modifies it, it is essential to synchronize accesses to it.  Some classes provide the needed synchronization automatically (their docs will tell you so), but most do not.  `java.util.ArrayList` does not.

There are several alternatives; one of the simpler would be to use `Collections.synchronizedList()` to create a synchronized wrapper around your `ArrayList`, and to use that (everywhere) instead of using the underlying `ArrayList` directly.

There are other potential gotchas in this area, but you appear to have already paid some attention to them.  For example, I see that you iterate the list elements by index, instead of by using an `Iterator` or enhanced `for` loop.  That will protect you from `ConcurrentModificationException`s.  Iterating backward from the initial list size also plays well with some of the possible problems that might arise from elements being added to the list by another thread, but beware of the possible effects of elements being removed.

Comment: I changed the declaration to     List<LocationData> locationUpdates = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<LocationData>());
Is it all that's required ?

Comment: @AkshayJ, that is all that is required to use the synchronized wrapper.  Not having a complete example, however, I cannot be certain whether it constitutes a complete solution to your problem.  It does solve all thread-safety problems that I see in what you presented.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `Collections.synchronizedList(locationUpdates);` or you put your list accesses into synchronized blocks:

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
....extra code here

        synchronized (locationUpdates) {
            locationUpdates.add(locationData);
        }

....extra code here
    }
```

And in your AsyncTask:

```
private class InsertTripDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                synchronized (locationUpdates) {
                    for (int i = locationUpdates.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        ArrayList<PropertyInfo> props = new ArrayList<PropertyInfo>();
                        props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("TripID", tripID, String.class));
                        props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("LocationTime", locationUpdates.get(i).LocationTime, String.class));
                        props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("Latitude", locationUpdates.get(i).Latitude, String.class));
                        props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("Longitude", locationUpdates.get(i).Longitude, String.class));
                       props.add(MyUtils.CreateProp("TripSpeed", locationUpdates.get(i).SpeedKMPH, String.class));

                        String response = MyUtils.getResponse("InsertTripDetail", props);

                        if (response.equals("yes")) {
                            locationUpdates.remove(i);
                            sentData++;
                            SetSentBufferedData();
                            PlayTone();
                        }
                        PlayInternetAlertIfNeeded();
                    }

                    if(isCancelled() && (locationUpdates.size()==0)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the second option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

---

To **read** from `ArrayList`, use:

```
ReentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().lock()
```

and

```
ReentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().unlock()
```

To **write** to it, use:

```
ReentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().lock()
```

and

```
ReentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().unlock()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14548797)

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Is my post now correct? Sorry about that.

Comment: yes, that looks good.  I edited the code a bit to make it more readable.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Thank you very much.

Comment: @AkshayJ Do the action between `lock()` and `unlock()`. I usually put `lock()` and do the action to the list in the `try` block, and put the `unlock()` in the `finally` block.